# Is there a simple way in JavaScript to get a string representation of its attributes?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I would like to output the attributes of an event object in an `alert()` call.

1) Is there a simple expression I can put in the alert call that will output all the attributes of the event?

2) Is there a simpler way of seeing the keys and values of the attributes (compared with `alert()`) that I should consider?

Comment: `Object.keys()` gives you all attribute names. `Object.entries()` gives you all attribute names and values. To inspect an object, maybe better use `console.log()` or the debug tab of your dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

1) To get the attributes of an event with their associated values, you can pass the following expressions to `alert()`:

- `Object.entries(event)`
- `JSON.stringify(event)`.

`Object.entries(event)` is the least concise because you need to convert the array to a string, but it gives you the most control over what your output looks like. `JSON.stringify(event)` is more concise, it has optional arguments that let you format the output a bit, and it provides the most transferable output as JSON is widely supported.

Alternatively, you can use the console instead of alert, and just pass the a variable representing an Event object (`console.log(event)`). Based on what you have expressed, `console.log(event)` is what you want because it will give you all the information you want with the least amount of code. The following point breaks down when these 2 output methods should be used.

---

2) Besides `alert()`, you can append the attributes as text to an element in the DOM or use `console.log()` to write the attributes to the console.

Writing to the console is the easiest way to output, but not useful for giving information to the end user. Writing the information to the DOM requires more code, but it's the best way to present information to the user. `alert()` should be used to deliver very basic messages (confirmations, warnings, etc.).

If your only goal is to see the keys and values of any given object, then `console.log()` is the best way to do this because it is easier to read and requires very little code.

---

```js
$('#a').on('click', (event) => console.log(event) )

$('#b').on('click', (event) => alert(JSON.stringify(event)) )

$('#c').on('click', (event) => $('#out').html(Object.entries(event).join(', ')) )
```

```css
.box {
  color: white;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
}

#a {background-color: green}

#b {background-color: blue}

#c {background-color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="box" id="a"> Console </button>
<button class="box" id="b"> Alert </button>
<button class="box" id="c"> Element </button>

<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: I see (at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) that `entries` does not produce an output string, but rather a set of key/value pairs. I was looking for something like Ruby's `to_s` or Java's `to_string` that would create the string representation of the entire set of key/value pairs for me. Sometimes objects in those languages don't have a custom "to string" function, but do have a "to hash" function that can then easily be represented as a string by calling the hash's "to string" method. Is there anything like that in JavaScript?

Comment: So far, `console.log(event);` seems to be the best solution for me, since it handles this for me.

Comment: The only problem with `console.log(event)` is how large the output is. It's not easy to read. But at the end of the day, reading the attributes and values of an event object wont look nice no matter how you present it. Also, in your question you only mention attributes, but it sounds like you also want to see their values. Is this correct? In regards to `Object.entries()`, it doesn't produce an output string but you can `.map()` the key-value pairs to a string and join the array of strings. It basically just gives you an easy way to format the key-value pairs.

Comment: I've edited the question to number my questions and clarify that I need both keys and values of the attributes. Thanks for your answer to #2, but regarding your answer to #1, I need both keys and values, and wanted a concise solution, which would probably rule out iterating over the keys and values myself.

Comment: Ok, I have adjusted by answer accordingly. `console.log(event)` is what you're looking for. Let me know if there's anything else I can clear up for you.

Comment: The event entries seem to consist of a single key/value pair: `"isTrusted" -> true`. Is it that all the values I am looking for (e.g. `target`) are functions but not attributes?

Comment: Are you referring to the output given by `Object.entries()`? If so, then the values you are seeing are either the primitive types (booleans, numbers, strings, etc.), or they are objects and you will see a value like `[object HTMLButtonElement]`. Functions are considered objects in JS, and different consoles will handle the display of functions as differently.